# Googlebot throws "TypeError: Failed to fetch" errors on POST despite good CORS response headers

Tags: javascript, cors, googlebot

I have a `try`/`catch` around a `fetch` JavaScript call that reports caught errors. I periodically get the following report about "TypeError: Failed to fetch" exceptions from Googlebot requests:

```
[2023-09-21T00:00:00.031Z] POST https://findhumane.com/find_humane/api/get_location_details?v=12.1.20230917
[2023-09-21T00:00:00.034Z] handleErrors: Failed to fetch (class: TypeError)
...
      HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.5938.88 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

While there are [many potential causes for `TypeError` during `fetch`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-api), the most common is improper CORS response headers, but I don't see any problems from Chrome network inspector when I perform the same use case manually; for example, it shows good CORS headers:

```
POST https://findhumane.com/find_humane/api/get_location_details?v=12.1.20230917
200 OK

Response Headers:

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 7200
...
```

The odd thing is that since I'm getting the exception email from the exception `catch` that is being `POST`ed to the same domain, then I don't know what the difference is between that `fetch` and this application `fetch`.

Any ideas or how I can debug further? I have two ideas:

1. Run a tcpdump on my backend all the time between my reverse proxy (HAProxy) and app server without TLS and then correlate to the Googlebot exception email to confirm 100% that the right CORS response headers are being sent.
2. Maybe I can somehow route the console into an in-memory string and report other console warnings/errors in my exception email?

I do have a 60 second timeout abort on the `fetch`:

```js
try {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), 60000);
  const response = await fetch(
    uri,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      signal: controller.signal,
    },
  );
  ...
```

However, the timestamps above show the `TypeError` occurred about 3 milliseconds after the request started.

Comment: There should be another, OPTIONS, request, because POSTing application/json requires a [CORS preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request). Does that also have the necessary response headers?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Thanks for the idea. I checked and my server is responding with proper CORS headers for an `OPTIONS` request.